# Dependency Injection Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5.1

I have a Facade Class

```
use App\Http\Response 

class RUser
{
    public function signup(TokenGenerator $token_generator, $data)
    {
        $response = [];
        $access_token = $token_generator->generate(32);
        dd($access_token);
        $user = User::create($data);
        $response['user_id'] = $user->_id;
        $response[''];
    }
}
```

Now from my `UserController` I am trying to use the `RUser::signup()` function like below

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $payload = json_decode($this->request->getContent());
        if($this->validateJson('user.create', $payload)) {
            $validator = Validator::make((array) $payload, User::$rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $messages = $validator->errors();
                return $this->sendResponse(false, $messages);
            }
            FUser::signup($payload);
            return $this->sendResponse(true, $response);
        }
    }
}
```

I think Laravel resolves these dependency automatically and i shound not be passing the instance of `TokenGenerator` explicitly. But i am getting the following error.

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Responses\RUser::signup() must be an instance of App\Utils\TokenGenerator, instance of stdClass given, called in
```

Comment: you need to pass object of `TokenGenerator` as first parameter of `signup` function

Comment: Is there something like binding into Laravel IOC ?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel injects instances in custom classes only in constructors by default. Controller actions will also receive instances injected.

So your example will need such changes to work properly:

```
class RUser
{
    protected $token_generator;

    public function __construct(TokenGenerator $token_generator)
    {
        $this->token_generator = $token_generator;
    }

    public function signup($data)
    {
        $response = [];
        $access_token = $this->token_generator->generate(32);
        dd($access_token);
        $user = User::create($data);
        $response['user_id'] = $user->_id;
        $response[''];
    }
}
```

and

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, RUser $ruser)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $payload = json_decode($this->request->getContent());
        if($this->validateJson('user.create', $payload)) {
            $validator = Validator::make((array) $payload, User::$rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $messages = $validator->errors();
                return $this->sendResponse(false, $messages);
            }
            $ruser->signup($payload);
            return $this->sendResponse(true, $response);
        }
    }
}
```

To trigger dependency injection outside when you instantiate class on your own you need to call `make()` method of Illuminate\Foundation\Application instance, like this:

```
$fooBar = $this->app->make('FooBar');
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/container#resolving)

Comment: Not working :S `Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Responses\RUser::__construct() must be an instance of App\Utils\TokenGenerator, none given, called in called in /var/www/html/myapp/app/Providers/RUserServiceProvider.php on line 29 and defined`

Comment: You are probably initializing it calling constructor directly in Service Provider. In such a case dependency injection won't happen. You can create it using `$ruser = $this->app->make('RUser');` construction.

Comment: Where should i do this ? If you are free i actually created a new question with all the codes so that people can know whats going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36203271/laravel-di-not-working-when-using-in-facades-underlying-class

Comment: `/var/www/html/myapp/app/Providers/RUserServiceProvider.php on line 29`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused with the use of Facades and Dependency Injection.
The thing you should follow here is dependence injection upto my knowledge you can use the class directly in here and it will work without any problem [TO have a clear idea of when to use facades and when to use dependency injection check this link](https://github.com/fideloper/Implementing-Laravel/issues/4)