# Laravel DI not working when using in Facades Underlying Class

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

This is my Facades Class

```
<?php 

namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class UserFacade extends Facade 
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

This is how i bind into IOC (Not sure if i am using correct terms)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class RUserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        App::bind('user', function() {
            return new \App\Http\Responses\RUser;
        });
    }
}
```

This is the Underlying class that contains actual code for user entity

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use App\Utils\TokenGenerator;
use App\Models\User;
use Validator;
use Hash;

class RUser
{
    protected $token_generator;

    public function __construct(TokenGenerator $token_generator)
    {
        $this->token_generator = $token_generator;
    }

    /**
     * Signup User
     * @param  Request $request 
     * @return array $response
     */
    public function signup($data)
    {
        $response = [];
        $access_token = $this->token_generator->generate(32);
        $user = User::create([
            'email' => $data->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($data->password),
            'company_name' => $data->company_name,
            'access_token' => $access_token
        ]);
        $response['user_id'] = $user->_id;
        $response['access_token'] = $user->access_token;
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And this is how i am using my RUser class in my UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Validator;
use FUser;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Signup User
     * @param  Request $request 
     * @return array $response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $payload = json_decode($this->request->getContent());
        if($this->validateJson('user.create', $payload)) {
            $validator = Validator::make((array) $payload, User::$rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                $messages = $validator->errors();
                return $this->sendResponse(false, $messages);
            }

            $response = FUser::signup($payload);
            return $this->sendResponse(true, $response);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is in my RUser class i am expecting Laravel to inject the TokenGenerator Dependency automatically as it normally inject dependencies in Controller classes. But i do not understand why it is not doing so.

This is what i am getting

> ErrorException in RUser.php line 15: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Responses\RUser::__construct() must be an instance of
>   App\Utils\TokenGenerator, none given, called in
>   /var/www/html/MyApp/app/Providers/RUserServiceProvider.php on line 29
>   and defined

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957790/how-do-i-create-a-facade-class-with-laravel) might help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the container to inject dependencies, you need to use the container's `make()` method instead of the native `new` operator:

```php
App::bind('user', function($app) {
    return $app->make('App\Http\Responses\RUser');
});
```

which can be written more concisely as:

```php
App::bind('user', 'App\Http\Responses\RUser');
```